# Kettle '?' not working Table Input Step

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I want to get all the table names from the database and then get all the rows from the tables. So I created a transformation like this:

1. Get Table Names: Added the database connection and stored the table name in a output field called "tablename".
2. Table Input: Marked "Replace variables in script" and "Execute for each row". Added the first step in "Insert data from step". SQL is "SELECT * from ?".
   I have read up a lot of tutorials online, including the [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Table+Input).
   My problem is that everywhere it says that I my "?" should be replaced with the parameter. But this does not happen. Here are the logs:

> 2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Get table names.0 - Starting to run...
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Postgres 9.1.9 RO - read :9 table names from db meta-data.
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - Query parameters found = [stackexchange2]
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - SQL query : SELECT * from ?
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException:
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : An error occurred executing SQL:
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : SELECT * from ?
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
>   Position: 16
>   2013/06/22 03:33:25 - Table input.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   
>   
>   I am using Kettle 4.4. Downloaded the spoon client from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/4.4.0-stable/).

**UPDATE**
I just want to make this work. I am learning the tool right now, and it would be good to know how '?' works.

Comment: Kettle is a metadata oriented ETL tool. Table metadata is initialized during transform initialization. You would never write one transform that operates on all tables in a database. Can you say more about what you're really trying to acccomplish?

Comment: Why not? I am testing the software. I want to be able to go through all the tables. My SQL statement might change to do something meaningful. But for now, I am following the tutorials, so this should work right?

Comment: And what's the best way of going through the tables?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: You can just see the [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Table+Input). Below they have an example where they show how '?' works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your situation, i prefer to work with jobs, please find {kettle_intalation_folder_path}/examples/jobs/process all tables/Process all tables.kjb, because your case is a simplification of that example.

Comment: I would still love to know how to fix that issue! :) But this helps a lot! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do this and you absolutely would do this.  Take a look at "Metadata Injection".

Also you can't parameterise a table name - jdbc doesnt allow this.  However you can get away with using the SQL step rather than table input and generate the whole SQL string in a field if you really want to. Wouldnt really recommend that though.

As said above, please describe further exactly what you're trying to do.  If you're just migrating a database without doing any transformation of the data, i.e. from one db to another, then dont bother with Kettle as thats not what it's for.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. No, I am not migrating db. Kettle has a very simple wizard for that.
If you see the log, "Query parameters found = [stackexchange2]". 'stackexchange2' is the table name. I am clearly getting it, and it is being passed to the next step. Even if I change the SQL statement to something else, for e.g. "select * from stackexchange2 where ?", it still doesnt replace the '?'.

Comment: And following the [documentation](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Table+Input) it should be possible.

Comment: err, can you attach a screen shot of your table input step then?

Comment: I need at least 10 rep to post images. Anyway, it doesn't matter much, the table input step is very simple. I have described it in my question

Comment: yes, and it works. so have you put in the "insert from previous step" dropdown?  and have you correctly selected the name of the previous step?  This all works correctly, I use it day in day out, so your problem is one of 2 things, either your step is misconfigured, or something in the stream is wrong.