# How to pass a table name as an input in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I am making a pentaho transformation and using a table input. The condition is that the name of the table will be passed dynamically as an argument. So the table input has the sql:

```
select * from ?
```

And this table input takes the input from a `Get Variables` step where i have defined a varibale called `'table_name'`. When i run the transformation i pass in the tablename.

I need to do it this way because the table name is of the form abc_ddmmyyyy and ddmmyyyy can vary.

Comment: Thanks I found the answere here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243319/kettle-not-working-table-input-step

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using metadata injection? Here is an article that could help:
http://www.pentahoevalcenter.com/data-integration/dynamic-step-metadata/

There is also an article on running a transformation once per filename:
http://www.timbert.net/doku.php?id=techie:kettle:jobs:processtransonceperfile

Answer (score 0):

This can solve through using java code for this first you set parameter in Edit->Settings and see parameter tab and add your parameter suppose parameter name like TABLE_NAME then write java code as below

```
import org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment;
import org.pentaho.di.core.Result;
import org.pentaho.di.core.RowMetaAndData;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException;
import org.pentaho.di.core.util.EnvUtil;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.Trans;
import org.pentaho.di.trans.TransMeta;
```

The above jar found in pdi lib folder. and set table name as below

```
KettleEnvironment.init(false);
                EnvUtil.environmentInit();
                TransMeta transmeta = new TransMeta("path of your ktr file");
                Trans trans = new Trans(transmeta);
                trans.setParameterValue("TABLE_NAME",your_table_name );
                trans.execute(null); 
                trans.waitUntilFinished();
                Result r = trans.getResult();
                List<RowMetaAndData> rowsResult = r.getRows();
                System.out.println(trans.getTransMeta());
                 if (trans.getErrors() > 0) {
                 throw new RuntimeException();
                 }
```

And write in your ktr table query like `select * from ${TABLE_NAME}`

Answer (score 0):

use variables like ${TABLE_NAME}. ? means prepared statement, won't do good to your work.